# Avoiding a nested subquery containing a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

Is there a better way to perform this query without using a nested subquery?

```
-- select all races for jockeys which have multiple regions
select distinct r.id, r.description
from jockeys_races jra inner join races r on r.id = jra.race_id
where jra.jockey_id in (
    select jre.jockey_id
    from jockeys_regions jre
    group by jre.jockey_id
    having count(*) > 1
);
```

Jockeys can belong to multiple regions. Jockeys can be in multiple races.

Comment: not that I know of, though I would probably use a 'where Exists' statement rather than an 'where feild IN()'. thats just personal preference though.

Comment: @FrankThomas . . . In MySQL, using EXISTS is not just a personal preference.  The queries optimize much better with EXISTS rather than IN with a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be as efficient (since the product will be larger), but you can do it.  Check the EXPLAIN on both.

```
select distinct r.id, r.description
from races r
  inner join jockey_races jra on r.id = jra.race_id
  inner join jockey_regions jre on jra.jockey_id = jre.jockey_id
group by r.id, r.description, jre.jockey_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: The problem with this query is that the join from races to jockey_races may produce duplicates.  These would then be counted, so this does not return the same results as the original query.

Comment: With the test data that I created, they both produce the same results.  The HAVING and the DISTINCT do the voodoo.   (The test data had multiple races, differing sets of jockeys per race, and differing numbers of regions per jockey, which seemed to match the original specs).

Comment: Accepting this answer as I don't think it is producing duplicates but I will evaluate it further. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, I believe:

```
select distinct r.id, r.description
from jockeys_races jra 
inner join races r on r.id = jra.race_id
inner join jockeys_regions jre on jre.jockey_id=jra.jockey_id
group by r.id, r.description, jre.jockey_id
having count(jre.region) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use IN with a subquery in MySQL . . . the optimizer does a very poor job with this construct.  In this case, you can move the subquery to the FROM clause:

```
select distinct r.id, r.description
from jockeys_races jra inner join
     races r
     on r.id = jra.race_id join
     (select jre.jockey_id
      from jockeys_regions jre
      group by jre.jockey_id
      having count(*) > 1
     ) ji
     on jra.jockey_id = ji.jockey_id
```

Comment: Didn't answer the original question but good advice regardless. Thanks!